# Display a modal conditionally on page load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a form in my view, and upon submission, my controller validates the fields and returns a list of errors in @errors, if any.

Now, I want to display these errors in a modal.

Here's what I have in my View:

```
!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <%= render 'shared/errors' %>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I want to display this modal on page load, if and only if @errors exists.

It looks like coffeescripts don't have access to variables passed by the controller.

I came across a few similar questions, but none of them seem to solve my problem.

Comment: 1 idea is, don't render the modal itself, when `@error.present` returns `false`. And that can be done in ERB, no need JS help.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I get the modal to show if the condition is true, without using JS?

Comment: Then you need to put the JS code in the view itself wrapping inside [`javascript_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-javascript_tag) tag.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with the help of gon gem.

1. Add "gem 'gon'" to your Gemfile.
2. run bundle install.
3. set value in controller like this: gon.form_errors = true  if @errors.present?
4. Add this line in application layout in head section before all javascript include tags:- For rails 4: <%= Gon::Base.render_data %> and for rails 3  <%= include_gon %>
5. Now you can access this variable in your coffee file like this: gon.variable_name and use it like this:

   ```
   if gon.form_errors

      $('#your-modal-id').modal('show')
   ```